# I want to upload image on localhost with text and delete or search that using searchbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have implemented the uploading image and showing the image on a webpage. I want to add some text description with it while uploading and after uploading that, from the search bar, I want to search the image description. For example if I upload 4 images:

> 1st image with abc text
>   2nd image with agh text
>   3rd image with xyz text
>   4th image with aaa text

After entering `a` in search input text, it should show 1,2 and 4 images, it should hide 3rd images.

```
var get = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var uploadedImg = uploadedImg || {};
uploadedImg.handleFileSelect = function(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object.

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

        // Only process image files.
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }

        var reader = new FileReader();

        //closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            return function(e) {
                // Render thumbnail.
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                get('thumbnails').insertBefore(span, null);
            };
        })(f);

        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}
get('imageUploaded').addEventListener('change', uploadedImg.handleFileSelect, false);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mohitpatil/c6vrag5z/3/

Comment: You may need to store those text along with the image in database and later perform search operation against the text entered

Comment: Thanks for edit @TylerH